# Value getting popped and stored in a variable even when stack is empty

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am using the co-processor 80387 to calculate the mean of some given number in data segment and probably  popped everything from the stack frame.
At last, I'm trying to pop a value from the empty stack into a variable named "pot" and later printing the variable using printf.
By, why is the value getting popped in "pot"  even when the stack is empty ?

Here is the code :

```
%macro print 2
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall     
%endmacro

%macro exit 0
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
%endmacro

extern printf
extern scanf


section .bss
    sum resq 1
    variance resq 2
    mean resq 1
    std_dev resq 1

    temp resq 1
    showarr resb 16

    pot resb 8
section .data
    menu db 10," "
    lenmenu equ $-menu

    msgvar db 10," : "
    lenvar equ $-msgvar

    msgmean db 10,"Enter the first number : ",10
    len1 equ $-msgmean

    arr dq 1h,1h,1h,1h,1h
    tot dq 5h
    frmt1 db 10,"Total %d elements present ",10,0
    frmt2 db 10,"Mean : %lf ",10,0
    frmt3 db 10,"Variance : %lf",10,0
    frmt4 db 10,"Std_Dev. : %lf",10,0

    frmtp db 10,"top: %ld",10,0
    newline db 0AH

    tt dq 3

section .code
global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp 

    finit
    fldz
    mov rsi,arr
    mov rcx,[tot]
    back:

        fadd qword[rsi]
        add rsi,8
    loop back

    fst qword[sum]

    mov rax,0;
    mov rdi,frmt1
    mov rsi,qword[tot]
    call printf

    fdiv qword[tot]; 
    fstp qword[mean]

    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,frmt2
    movq xmm0,qword[mean]
    call printf


    fstp qword[pot]

    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,frmtp
    movq xmm0,qword[pot]
    call printf

    mov rsp,rbp
    pop rbp


exit
```

Comment: You didn’t mention the output you get  when you print the value in ‘pot’. I guess it is garbage, since you use an integer format but pass the value in xmm0 instead of rsi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x87 generates the floating point exception #IS for stack underflow, but this exception can be masked. Furthermore, the exception is not generated until the next x87 instruction, and in your program there isn’t one.

If the exception is masked, the x87 stores an “indefinite value” in the destination. If the exception is not masked, nothing is stored.

The floating point indefinite value is a QNAN with all bits in the fraction set to 0 (except the most significant fraction bit is 1, making it a QNAN instead of an SNAN).